# Is $Alt_\omega$ a dense subgroup of a non-discrete locally compact topological group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Let $S_\omega$ be the group of bijections of the countable ordinal $\omega:=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ and $Alt_\omega$ be the subgroup of $S_\omega$ consisting of even permutations of $\omega$ (i.e., the compositions of even number of transpositions). By [Onofri-Schreier-Ulam Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166358/normal-subgroups-of-infinite-symmetric-group/2645097#2645097), $Alt_\omega$ is the smallest non-trivial normal subgroup in the permutation group $S_\omega$.

It is known that

$\bullet$ [the group $Alt_\omega$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of a compact topological group;](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3420/countable-subgroups-of-compact-groups/62857#62857)

$\bullet$ [the group $S_\omega$ is not isomorphic to a dense subgroup of a non-discrete locally compact topological groups.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293614/is-each-locally-compact-group-topology-on-the-permutation-group-discrete/293619#293619)

These two results motivate the following

> **Problem 1.** Is the group $Alt_\omega$ isomorphic to a dense subgroup of a non-discrete locally compact topological group?

Since the group $Alt_\omega$ is simple, this problem can be reformulated in the following form.

> **Problem 2.** Let $h:Alt_\omega\to G$ be a homomorphism of $Alt_\omega$ to a locally compact topological group $G$. Is the image $h(Alt_\omega)$ discerete?

**Remark.** By the answer of @YCor to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293614/is-each-locally-compact-group-topology-on-the-permutation-group-discrete/293638#293638), 
for every homomorphism $h:S_\omega\to G$ to a locally compact topological group $G$ the image $h(S_\omega)$ is discrete.

Comment: What is the definition of $Alt_\omega$, there is a subgroup of even permutations of finite support, is that what you mean? Why don't you ask it for $S^{fin}_\omega$ first?

Comment: @AndreasThom You are right: $Alt_\omega$ is the subgroup of even permutations (with automatically finite support). I wrote the definition in the third line of the question: the composition of even number of pemutations. Why $Alt_\omega$? Because it is a smallest normal subgroup of $S_\omega$ and the answer for $Alt_\omega$ will imply the answer for all larger subgroups of $S_\omega$, including $S_\omega^{fin}$. I think that the questions for $Alt_\omega$ and $S_\omega^{fin}$ could be equivalent (as $Alt_\omega$ has index 2 in $S_\omega^{fin}$).

Comment: I cannot understand what is wrong with this question that it has got two downvotes. A question as many other questions. At least it has a natural motivation. What is wrong? Istead of demonstrating the power in downvoting, better suggest a solution!

Comment: @TarasBanakh the result that $Alt_\omega$ is the minimal nontrivial normal subgroup in $Sym(\omega)$ was first proved by Onofri in 1929, reproved 4 years later by Schreier-Ulam, and owes nothing to Baer (who generalized to uncountable cardinals). https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2645097/35400

Comment: @YCor Thank you for the info. I made the corresponding changes in the text of OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corollary 1.5 of [this Vissarion Belyaev's paper](http://mi.mathnet.ru/smj1670) says that

> A group containing an infinite inert residually finite subgroup
>   embeds into a non-discrete locally compact group.

Here, a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called *inert* if $H\cap g^{-1}Hg$ has a finite index in $H$ for any $g\in G$.

So, in the alternating group $Alt_\omega$, for instance, the (abelian) subgroup generated by the 3-cycles $(1\;2\;3),(4\;5\;6),(7\;8\;9),\dots$
is inert. infinite, and residually finite .

Thus, the answer to Question 1 is **yes** (and to Question 2 is **no**).

Comment: Anton, thank you for the answer! Truly speaking, I expected that it will be opposite.

Comment: The emphasized statement is (essentially) originally due to Schlichting, 1980. At least Schlichting's construction applies here. On the other hand, I think the first explicit dense embeddings of the alternating group into a locally compact group are in Willis' J. Algebra 2007 paper.

Comment: Yves, it seems that  Belyaev was unaware of Schlichting's work. But this is not just "a construction". This is actually a criterion: *a group $G$ is isomorphic to a dense subgroup of a totally disconnected non-discrete locally compact group if and only if  $G$ contains an infinite inert residually finite subgroup* (I am citing Belyaev's paper)..

Comment: Taras, you are welcome. The symmetric group and finitary symmetric group are quite different.